# How to obtain currency rates from this website converter widget python

Tags: python, web, module, web-scraping

How can I implement the currency rates on this website and keep the currencies up to date so that i can access them in python from this website and input and output values and currencies types. I need my program to connect to this webpage and take the rates of the currency using the currency converter app on the webpage.

[This is the website](https://travelmoney.travelex.co.uk/virgin/Basket)

I need to know how to do this on many high street currency providers that have a website however many do not supply a list of rates so web scraping is not as straightforward.

Which modules will i need to install using pip and how will i be able to use them to achieve my goal.
Many thanks

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/ - Try lxml

Comment: @henchness It also might be helpful to take a look at the website's source (e.g. using Control+U in chrome). All of the conversion-data is on one convenient line in this case containing `{"AED":` immediately after `{"foreignCurrencyAsBase":false,"rates":`. You could just download the html webpage using python's `urllib` or `urllib2` libraries, read the lines in, and look for a line that starts with this if you want a "quick and dirty" solution.

Comment: Which solution would do my task in the least lines of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code where exchange_rates is a dict mapping currencies to their rates (the url is the one that [this](https://travelmoney.travelex.co.uk/Virgin/widget/ExchangeRates) page uses to load it's data)

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.travelex.net/salt/config/multi?key=Travelex&site=%2Fvirgin&options=abhikzl"
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)
exchange_rates = data['rates']['rates']

for item in exchange_rates:
    print("{}, {}".format(item, exchange_rates[item]))
```

You can apply this to most sites by loading them with the [chrome developer network window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) open and look through the requests to find the one that loads in this data.

Comment: On the last line of this code I get a "invalid syntax" error after the speech marks.

Comment: that means you are using python 3, I have changed the example to work for you!