# How to obtain rates from currency exchange sites that use travelex api PYTHON

Tags: python, api, currency, converters

I am stuck on trying to retrieve live currency rates from these websites that go through Travelex to get rates such as https://travelmoney.tescobank.com/tb/page/ratechart/

I have obtained some currency rates by web scraping however for some link tesco money or john lewis money I cannot find a way on how to get the rates.I have tried to use Travelex's Salt API but I do not have a key for it and there email branch for the api is not working.
I am creating a python currency converter by the way

Thanks

Comment: "however for some... I cannot find a way on how to get the rates" - What is you actual question? Is there an error you are dealing with? Nobody on SO will simply code a solution to scrape data from Tesco for you. You need to tell us what you've tried and why that particular site is causing an issue. Try providing the code you are using successfully to scrape other sites.

Comment: I have used web scrapping for XE and google finance currency such as getting the link and searching the html for the specific class that holds the value

Comment: ...Yeah, that's how you'd do it. So what's the problem with Tesco and John Lewis?

Comment: For Virgin money i have used the answer of this link. Virgin money uses travelex to get rates and so does tesco money but i dont know how to adadpt the answer from here for use on tesco moneys currency                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166750/how-to-obtain-currency-rates-from-this-website-converter-widget-python

Comment: I need adapt the api for use of tesco money. I have read this but i need a key to use it and have emailed travelex but have got a error message http://api.travelex-dev.net/docs/api/index.html#api-General-getAddressSearch